# Set page number in all Chapter start pages with KOMA-Script

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, koma-script, report

I'm using the KOMA-Script to define my headings and I would like to show only the page number in the chapter start pages. I got this by creating a new style and using it with `\thispagestyle{ChapterStyle}` after the `\chapter{}`, but I have many chapters. **Is there a way to add only the page number automatically to all the chapter start pages?** Thanks for your attention and help!
Here follows what I've done:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,headtopline,footsepline,footbotline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\chead{\normalfont{\thechapter. \headmark}}
\cfoot{\pagemark}

% To define a page style
\deftripstyle{ChapterStyle}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\thispagestyle{ChapterStyle}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Four}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is a `chapter` page? The chapter start page?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, the chapter start page! Edited! Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware that `scrpage` is officially deprecated and replaced by `scrlayer-scrpage`. Please have that in mind for your next document.

Comment: btw, the most simple solution to the problem stated would be `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`. With the newest version (v3.14) `\cfoot*{\pagemark}`. There is absolutely no need to fiddle with page styles.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the remind on `scrpage2` I'll have a look into it! I have tried `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` before I asked the question, but the problem is that it adds a page number to my other headings, and it is not easy to define where to stop using it with `\cfoot[]{}`. If I have a `\lefoot{\pagemark}` for the heading `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` which is my real case, with `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` I get two page numbers in that heading one left and another in the center, if I have got you right!

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you have the pagemarks at a different position for non-`plain` pages, this solution wion't work. `\cfoot[\pagemark]{}` would be working here. I was just thinking as the reader, and as the reader i would expect the pagenumber to be at the same position in the whole document. But as long as it doesn't switch form head to foot over and over again, i think you'll be fine.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I also agree concerning the consistency in a layout. I just tried to say with my example what happens if that function is active and I actually missed to say that I shift the page number from right to left depending if the page is right or left, and there are also empty pages for making a chapter always start on the right side which also gets a page number with that function on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `report` the page style for `\chapter` is `plain` by default.  To change this you either need to change the `plain` page style, which may well have undesired side effects for other formatting in your document, or to patch the `\chapter` command to use your own style:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{ChapterStyle}{}{}
```

If you had been using `scrreprt` instead then there would be the easier mechanism of issuing

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{ChapterStyle}
```

A complete document for your `report` case is now:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,headtopline,footsepline,footbotline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\chead{\normalfont{\thechapter. \headmark}}
\cfoot{\pagemark}

% To define a page style
\deftripstyle{ChapterStyle}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{ChapterStyle}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Four}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: A very easy (and clever solution) -- But could not some other `plain` occur in the definition of KOMA `\chapter` etc. (I did not check, actually)

Comment: Andrew this is indeed a clever solution! I had found the solution for the case in `scrreprt`, but I was struggling with the `report` as I need to stick to it for now. Thanks for your help and attention!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The path solution is dealing with the standard report class and there in the standard definition the first occurrance of `plain` is the page style specification.  One could write `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{ChapterStyle}}{}{}` if you wanted to be certain about the match.  For KOMA `\chapter` one should use the other solution I mentioned.